# Neither "docker stop", "docker kill" nor "docker -f rm" works

Tags: docker, containers, dockerhub

Trying to stop container from [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jleight/opentsdb/) by using either of mentioned commands results in indefinite waiting by docker. The container still can be observed in `docker ps` output.

Sorry for a newbie question, but how does one stop containers properly?

This container was first run according to the instructions on hub.docker.com, halted by Ctrl+C and then started again by `docker start <containter-name>`. After it was started, it never worked as expected though.

Comment: It seems that the container runs supervisord with the following configuration file `https://github.com/jleight/docker-opentsdb/blob/master/supervisor.conf`, and in the file there is a setting `stopwaitsecs=60`. I wonder if that is the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test worked for me:

```
→ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
853e36b8a952        jleight/opentsdb    "/usr/bin/supervisord"   9 minutes ago           Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:4242->4242/tcp   fervent_hypatia

→ docker stop fervent_hypatia
fervent_hypatia

→ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

It took a bit long, but I think that is because the Docker image is using a supervisor process so SIGTERM (which is what docker stop sends first) doesn't kill the container, but the SIGKILL, which is by default sent after 10 seconds should (my wait time was ~ 10 seconds).

Just in case your default may be messed up for some reason, try indicating the timeout explicitely:

```
docker stop --time=2 <container-name>
```

Comment: i ended up killing VBox process after 5 minutes of waiting. later it didn't repeat itself, though it does take a while to stop this container.

Answer (score 2):

`docker stop <container-name>` is a proper way to stop your container. It's possible there is something going on inside, you could try using`docker logs <container-name>` to give you more information about what's running inside.

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted; in addition to implying a need for help killing the container, he/she explicitly asked "Sorry for a newbie question, but how does one stop containers properly?"

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the best way, but eventually restarting docker would do the trick, if nothing else works.